# Date function outputting wrong datetime

Tags: php, wordpress

Date function outputting wrong datetime in php.Now current datetime in india is 2013/07/27 23:10:12
but its outputting 2013/07/27 17:39:12.That is wrong please help me with the problem.

Thanks

Comment: php uses server time! look at [date_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-timezone-set.php) or [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: as @redreggae said, make sure your server has the correct time set

Comment: The above time is the time set on your server if you want to change your time zone you can change it using set Time function in php

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime function depends on the [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) set in the php.ini file of your server.

Uncomment the line in your php.ini file and set it to your timezone (refer to the link above to find the constant):

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Calcutta"
```

You can [set it with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
```

The best way to get the IP address is as follows:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

That's easy enough, but the hard part is mapping it to a timezone. There are a couple of databases that might help: [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) and [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/). However, your best solution might be to do it on the client side with a tool like [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home). Here's another [JavaScript solution](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/).

Comment: what to change in php.ini file so it should work fine.Because i want to get the local time of the user.If user in USA so it should get the UTC time.If in india so time should be according to india timezone. Thanks

Comment: You should not change PHP time on the fly. PHP is a server side language and the time should hold one timezone (servers time zone).

If you want to display time to the use based on location you should consider using javascript, or calculating the offset from your servers time zone then outputting that.

Comment: @CreativityKills - I'm not talking about changing server time - just changing the timezone for the DateTime object.

Comment: @ArunKumar - I just updated my answer for mapping IPs to timezones or other alternatives. I'm afraid that's about as much as I can do.

Comment: problem with this function date_i18n();